# Polygon another location

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, postgis, geo

Looking google maps have located 4 points and have created a polygon with them in this way

> insert into dummy_zip values (4,'prueba_directa','2016-04-13
>   08:08:15.973731','prueba_directa',1,1,100,'2016-04-13
>   08:08:15.973731',(SELECT
>   ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((37.986504
>   -1.121951,37.986741 -1.121243,37.985794 -1.120792,37.985608 -1.121479,37.986504 -1.121951)))',4326),900913)));

but when displayed on the map they are in a completely different location than where they should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the axis order, which should be (X Y) or (long lat).

You can use [ST_FlipCoordinates](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_FlipCoordinates.html) to fix any existing data.